# Help me to identify this stream insects

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

this insect I found on a stream in the southern region of Bangladesh. Its dorsal part is fully black and head and thorax is yellowish with black spot. Body size approx. 5-6mm, limbs 8-10mm

Comment: Where (what country, what region, what kind of stream, ...) did you find it? What is its approximate size? Was it alive when you got it? What can you tell us about its behaviour?

Comment: If I'm interpreting what I'm seeing correctly, you have some sort of Water Strider (Order Hemiptera, Family Gerridae) here; which one will depend on where you found it (and your name suggests that you might not be from the United States -- which means that I at least cannot go further).

Comment: Hey I am sorry I didn't give the details... I found it in Bangladesh southern region. Its body length is around 5-6 mm and it limbs are approximately 8-10 mm

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt at an answer**

I think it is a [water strider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerridae). There are 1700 species of water strider. Some of them are easy to eliminate (the marine ones typically) but I am not really able to give you more info from your picture.

To make sure, it is a water strider, can you please tell us
- How long are the legs (hard to tell form the picture)?
- If it was alive, was it standing on water? What can you tell us about its behaviour?

**What insects live in the water?**

If it is a stream insect, it could be...

- a mosquito larvea
- a mayfly larvea
- a odonate (dragonfly or damselfly) larvea
- a water strider

Here are my thoughts for each of them

- a mosquito larvea

  - No, mosquito larvea don't any limbs
- a mayfly larvea

  - I can't see the long cerci
- a odonate (dragonfly or damselfly) larvea

  - Again I can't see the cerci
  - Also, although, it is often hard to see, it does not appear to have a fancy detachable mouth piece.
- a water strider

  - We can't tell the length of the limbs from the picture. Were they really long?
  - If it was alive, was it standing on the water?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the above information will help me to find out the species

Comment: Although you may be right about it being a water strider, your answer is incomplete. There are a lot more water insects. Coleoptera, Trichoptera, other Hemiptera than water striders, other Diptera than mosquitos, etc.